# Draw border around a polygon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

```
    -(void)setTopRightCornerWithRadious:(CGFloat)radious View:(UIView*)vw
{
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:vw.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radious, radious)];
    [maskPath closePath];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = vw.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    vw.layer.mask=maskLayer;

    if (vw.layer.borderColor) {
        UIColor *color=[UIColor colorWithCGColor:vw.layer.borderColor];
        [color setStroke];
        maskLayer.accessibilityPath.lineWidth=1.0f;
        [maskLayer.accessibilityPath stroke];
    }
}
-(void)setAllBorderForView:(UIView*)vw Color:(UIColor*)color Thickness:(CGFloat)thick
{
    if (vw) {
        vw.layer.borderWidth=thick;
        vw.layer.borderColor=color.CGColor;
    }
}
```

[image]

I wish to draw a border surrounded by these two button. I tried so many times with CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath, but failed, may be I missed some thing. Some of them solve this problem using UIView, but I don't want that. I only want to solve the issues only by using the CAShapeLayer and/or UIBezierPath.

Here is my smaple code... WHere is my fault???? At very first i set the border, then I tried to set the corner. For few time may the border color exist or may not exist.

Comment: that dooesn't look like a polygon. Do you need a border for each of these buttons or one border for the two buttons ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri There is two separate button, and I want to place border surrounded by them individually, i.e. border will be for each of the button. And since I can't mention whether it is a square or rectangle, thats why I mention it as a polygon. May be I am wrong, please correct me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want to have space betweeen border and button,easiest way would be adding two bezier paths. One for the button, and one for the border else you can add stroke to the button bezier path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to have a border around the button, add stroke to the button bezier path.

[image]

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)frame
{
UIBezierPath* rectangle2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(x,y,widht,height) byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(17.25, 17.25)];
[rectangle2Path closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[rectangle2Path fill];
[UIColor.redColor setStroke];
rectangle2Path.lineWidth = 1;
[rectangle2Path stroke];
}
```

Or If you want to have space between the border and the button bezier path, then you should add two bezier paths. One for button, and another one for border.

[image]

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)frame
{

    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame), floor((CGRectGetWidth(frame)) * 1.00000 + 0.5), floor((CGRectGetHeight(frame)) * 1.00000 + 0.5)) byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(28, 28)];
    [rectanglePath closePath];
    [UIColor.redColor setStroke];
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1;
    [rectanglePath stroke];


    UIBezierPath* rectangle2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 7, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 8, 103, 62) byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(26, 26)];
    [rectangle2Path closePath];
    [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
    [rectangle2Path fill];
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Actually the situation is like above. I can only call two method applying which I have to make the corner along with the border color.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom button class you set this:

```
UIBezierPath outerPAth=  [UIBezierPath bezirePath];
    [[UIColor WhiteColor] setStroke];
    outlinePath.lineWidth=5.0;
    [outlinePath stroke];
```